String not changing
Idk why the orestring don't change 
when I write in script print(Orestring.Value) it normally works, it says that what should be in orestring but the orestring don't change
local proximityprompt = game.Workspace.Tycoons.Tycoon.MainItems.Cardboard_Box.Box.ProximityPrompt
local StorageGui = script.Parent
local x = script.Parent.Storage.Frame.X

local Orebuttons = script.Parent.Storage.Frame.Ores:GetChildren()
local OreString = script.Parent.Parent.Sell.Frame.Ore

proximityprompt.Triggered:Connect(function()

    StorageGui.Visible = true
end)
x.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    StorageGui.Visible = false
end)
for _, button: GuiButton in pairs(Orebuttons) do
    if button:IsA("GuiButton") then
        button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()

            OreString.Value = button.Name
        end)
    end
end


Is this a LocalScript or a Script? Where is this code located in the game?

You can likely checking the OreString.Value wrong if the print works fine, please provide the script that handles OreString.Value.

make sure the Ore object is a string, i hope this helps :D
